# How to add buttons dynamically?

Tags: android, button, layout

I want to add buttons dynamically. I am adding multiple buttons **dynamically** but I want to add the buttons in following pattern:

```
[BUTTON1] [BUTTON2]
[BUTTON3] [BUTTON4]
[BUTTON5] [BUTTON6]
```

That means I want to add only 2 buttons in a row that is dynamically.

I have tried many options.
one of them is:

```
 LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
    Button[][] buttonArray = new Button[count][count];
    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    for (int row = 0; row < count; row++) {
        TableRow currentRow = new TableRow(this);
        for (int button = 0; button < row; button++) {
            Button currentButton = new Button(this);
            // you could initialize them here
            currentButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            // you can store them
            buttonArray[row][button] = currentButton;
            // and you have to add them to the TableRow
            currentRow.addView(currentButton);
        }
        // a new row has been constructed -> add to table
        table.addView(currentRow);
    }
```

and finally takes that new table and add it to your layout. `ll.addView(table);`

**Note:** count of button could be random.

How can I do that?

Comment: Any previous attempts ? or just asking ?

Comment: please search on google .what you tried so far ?

Comment: Yes.. I have tried a lot.. please help..

Comment: already searched. but unable to find proper solution @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: You need to share with us what you tried and where it didn't work.

Comment: "I have tried a lot" > Then share that with us

Comment: using recyclerview? https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview

Comment: please find update of question @MehmetKologlu

Comment: I don't know how to do that. that's why I am asking. If you have proper solution then please share. @MehmetKologlu

Comment: Thanks.. what a solution you have suggested!! @MehmetKologlu

Answer (score 3):

Use vertical LinearLayout in XML. Then programmatically create horizontal LinearLayout and add buttons in horizontal layout. For each line, create and add new horizontal layout.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonlayout">
</LinearLayout>
```

ACTIVITY:

```
public class dynamicButtons extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int numberOfRows = 3;
    int numberOfButtonsPerRow = 2;
    int buttonIdNumber = 0;


    final LinearLayout verticalLayout= LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfRows;i++){
      LinearLayout newLine = new LinearLayout(this);
      newLine.setLayoutParams(params);
      newLine.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
      for(int j=0;j<numberOfButtonsPerRow;j++){
            Button button=new Button(this);
            // You can set button parameters here:
            button.setWidth(20);
            button.setId(buttonIdNumber);
            button.setLayoutParams(params);
            button.setText("Button Name");
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent is = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), someOtherApplication.class);
                    is.putExtra("buttonVariable", buttonIdNumber);
                    startActivity(is);
                }
            });

            newLine.addView(button);
            buttonIdNumber++;
      }
      verticalLayout.addView(newLine);

    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a listview/recyclerview with custom item that hold 2 button as you mentioned in your question, than populate that listView with the buttons (inside the adapter if item index % 2 == 0 it will take the left position otherwise the right position).

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
    LinearLayout ll_Main  = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    LinearLayout ll_Row01 = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    LinearLayout ll_Row02 = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

    ll_Main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll_Row01.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    ll_Row02.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    final Button button01    = new Button(getActivity());
    final Button button02    = new Button(getActivity());   
    final Button button03    = new Button(getActivity());
    final Button button04    = new Button(getActivity());

    ll_Row01.addView(button01);
    ll_Row01.addView(button02);

    ll_Row02.addView(button03);
    ll_Row02.addView(button04);

    ll_Main.addView(ll_Row01);
    ll_Main.addView(ll_Row02);

    button04.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    button04.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
TableLayout layout = new TableLayout (this);
    layout.setLayoutParams( new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {   //number of rows
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++) { //number of columns
            Button b = new Button (this);
            b.setText("Button:"+i+j);
            b.setTextSize(10.0f);
            b.setOnClickListener(this);
            tr.addView(b, 30,30);
        }
        layout.addView(tr);
    }
```

As your number of button is random u can use:

```
 int total = 20;  //random number of buttons
int column = 3;    //specify the column number
int row = total / column;
```

now use the `column` and `row` value to dynamically show buttons